# Proposing an O(logm) algorithm for the following

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I need to propose an algorithm for the following: let us assume that we have an array consisting of zeros and ones. The array is filled with zeros from the beginning of the array to the index m, and all remaining indexes are filled with ones. I need to find this index m in O(logm) time. Here is what i thought: I think this is like binary search, first i look at the middle element of the array, if that is zero, then i forget about the left part of the array and do the same for the right part, and continue like this until i encounter a one. If the middle element is one, then i forget about the right part and do the same for left part of the array. Is this a correct O(logm) solution? Thanks

Comment: Why don't you write the pseudocode, and then find out?

Comment: Actually, i was not sure whether my solution is O(logm) or O(logn) where n is the total size of array. Thanks for the downvote!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not *"like"* a binary search - it **is** a binary search. Unfortunately, it is `O(logN)`, not `O(logM)`.

To find the borderline in `O(logM)`, start from the other end: try positions `{1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ... 2^i}` and so on, until you hit a `1`. Then do a binary search on the interval between `2^i` and `2^(i+1)`, where `2^i+1` is the first position where you discovered a `1`.

Finding the first `1` takes `O(logM)`, because the index is doubled on each iteration. After that, the binary search takes another `O(logM)`, because the length of the interval `2^i..2^(i+1)` is less than `M` as well.

Comment: shouldn't it be between 2^(i) and 2^(i-1)?

Comment: oh ok you said  2^i+1 is the first position where i discovered a 1